# Como fazer um filtro antes de executar action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Antes de executar action, quero fazer um filtro para verificar se o valor existe.

Se o valor não existir, retornar para página específica(Index, Home).

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Poderia exemplificar melhor o que você deseja? Da forma que está ficou um pouco confusa

Comment: Ainda ficou um pouco confuso. O que você quer chamar? Isso irá ser para todos os controllers?

Comment: acredito que o que você precisa é criar um filtro que será executado antes de cada action do controller. veja esse artigo, talvez te ajude: http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-action-filters-entendendo-customizando/ 
pesquise por action filters se preferir

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou meio confusa mesmo, mas testa o código que eu postei na resposta, aqui funcionou certinho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar Action Filters para fazer isso. Um Action Filter é um atributo que você coloca em cima de cada action (ou no controller, para aplicar a todas as actions) indicando ao framework que, antes de executar a action, ele deve executar o seu filtro. Teste o código abaixo:

Código do home controller:

```
using MvcApplication1.ActionFilters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [MeuFilter]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Código do Filtro:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MvcApplication1.ActionFilters
{
    public class MeuFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

            if (controller != null)
            {
                if (session["Login"] == null)
                {
                    controller.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/About");
                }
            }

        }
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            // Implementar
        }
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Implementar
        }
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            //Implementar
        }
    }
}
```

Antes de executar a action Index, o "MeuFiltro" será executado, e nele eu estou verificando uma session de login, caso não exista, redireciona para outra action. Para criar um Action Filter é necessário herdar a classe ActionFilterAttribute e implementar a interface IActionFilter. Para mais detalhes sugiro ler [esse artigo](https://ozsenegal.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/asp-net-mvc-entendendo-action-filters/)

Comment: Valeu, funcionou aqui.